# App installation failure due to App Management Shared Service Proxy

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, deployment, sharepoint-addin, app

I have a SharePoint 2013 Foundation installation for development activity and when trying to deploy a SharePoint hosted App, I get the error:

> App Management Shared Service Proxy is not installed.

Here is the screen shot:[image]

I can see my App Management Service Application, Secure Store, and State Service running..

[image]

In my ULS logs I see the following errors:

```
Area        : SharePoint Foundation
Correlation : 7955379c-7996-f042-0000-0d66be182836
Category    : General
Level       : Medium
EventID     : 8nca
Message     : Application error when access 
              /_admin/sssvc/ManageSSSvcApplication.aspx, Error=The trial 
              period for this product has expired or Secure Store Shared 
              Service is not supported for this SKU.   at Microsoft.Office.Secu
              reStoreService.Server.SecureStoreServiceApplicationProxy.Execute[
              T](String operationName, Boolean validateCanary, 
              ExecuteDelegate`1 operation)     at Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreS
              ervice.Server.SecureStoreServiceApplicationProxy.IsMasterSecretKe
              yPopulated()     at Microsoft.Office.SharePoint.ClientExtensions.
              SecureStoreAdministration.SSSAdminHelper.EnsurePrerequisite(Secur
              eStoreServiceApplicationProxy proxy, String& errorMessage)     
              at Microsoft.Office.SharePoint.ClientExtensions.SecureStoreAdmini
              stration.ManageSSSvcApplication.InitializeGridView()     at 
              Microsoft.Office.SharePoi...

Area        : SharePoint Foundation
Correlation : 7955379c-7996-f042-0000-0d66be182836
Category    : Runtime
Level       : Unexpected
EventID     : tkau
Message     : Microsoft.Office.Server.ProductExpiredException: The trial 
              period for this product has expired or Secure Store Shared 
              Service is not supported for this SKU.    at Microsoft.Office.Sec
              ureStoreService.Server.SecureStoreServiceApplicationProxy.Execute
              [T](String operationName, Boolean validateCanary, 
              ExecuteDelegate`1 operation)     at Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreS
              ervice.Server.SecureStoreServiceApplicationProxy.IsMasterSecretKe
              yPopulated()     at Microsoft.Office.SharePoint.ClientExtensions.
              SecureStoreAdministration.SSSAdminHelper.EnsurePrerequisite(Secur
              eStoreServiceApplicationProxy proxy, String& errorMessage)     
              at Microsoft.Office.SharePoint.ClientExtensions.SecureStoreAdmini
              stration.ManageSSSvcApplication.InitializeGridView()     at 
              Microsoft.Office.SharePoint.ClientExtensions.SecureSto...

Area        : SharePoint Foundation
Correlation : 7955379c-7996-f042-0000-0d66be182836
Category    : General
Level       : High
EventID     : ajlz0
Message     : Getting Error Message for Exception 
              System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of 
              type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> 
              Microsoft.Office.Server.ProductExpiredException: The trial 
              period for this product has expired or Secure Store Shared 
              Service is not supported for this SKU.     at Microsoft.Office.Se
              cureStoreService.Server.SecureStoreServiceApplicationProxy.Execut
              e[T](String operationName, Boolean validateCanary, 
              ExecuteDelegate`1 operation)     at Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreS
              ervice.Server.SecureStoreServiceApplicationProxy.IsMasterSecretKe
              yPopulated()     at Microsoft.Office.SharePoint.ClientExtensions.
              SecureStoreAdministration.SSSAdminHelper.EnsurePrerequisite(Secur
              eStoreServiceApplicationProxy proxy, String& errorMessage)
```

Can somebody help me troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Not sure, but this thread suggests it is intact an acknowledged bug in foundation: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/fr-FR/707504d4-bd13-400a-8240-a35ce0258d79/the-trial-period-for-this-product-has-expired-or-secure-store-shared-service-is-not-supported-for

Comment: @RobertLindgren I did see that very thread you shared.. but couldn't find a fix. But I don't understand why it comes up when I deploy an App!!

Comment: Me neither, but that's why I said they call it a bug

Answer (score 2):

**Error occurred in deployment step ‘Install App for SharePoint’: App Management Shared Service Proxy is not installed.**

While deploying getting this error..
“App Management Shared Service Proxy is not installed”

To resolve this..
- Go to Central Admin > Application Management > Manage service applications.. make sure that the following services are running..

- App Management Service
- Secure Store Service
- Security Token Service Application

[image]

If App Management service is not yet provisioned, you can skip it for now, as it will be done later through powershell later.

**Error occurred in deployment step ‘Install App for SharePoint’: Failed to install App for SharePoint.**

Once you have the necessary services started, Follow the steps provided in the “Configure an isolated app domain to create and deploy SharePoint-hosted apps” section of this article..[How to: Set up an on-premises development environment for apps for SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179923.aspx)

For step#2: Set-SPAppDomain “your app domain” .. I used: Set-SPAppDomain “apps.sp2013domain.com”
So when I set the IE proxy “Add your isolated app domain to your bypass list in Internet Explorer”, here is the settings that worked for me

[image]

For step#7: if you get the error
“Set-SPAppSiteSubscriptionName : The requested service, `http://localhost:32843/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/securitytoken.svc/actas` could not be activated. See the server’s diagnostic trace logs for more information.”
just do an iisreset or free up some RAM memory. This service needs at least 5% of the total RAM for its purpose.

Source link http://www.howtosp.com/blog/2012/07/21/app-management-shared-service-proxy-is-not-installed/

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SP.SE @Unit06. This link may very well answer the question, however we like you to add relevant information in your post and use the link as reference. The link may break in the future,  and the answer will in this case be useless. So please, edit your answer. Once again, welcome

Comment: why did this answer get a down vote, without any explanation?