# App Management Shared Service Proxy is not installed

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, services

I'm facing this issue first time, While **publishing** the designer workflow getting error as-

**App Management Shared Service Proxy is not installed**

I've checked this [answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/74735/app-installation-failure-due-to-app-management-shared-service-proxy#answer-82674), [link1](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/error-app-management-shared-service-proxy-is-not-installed/) and [link2](https://epmpoint.wordpress.com/2014/08/06/sharepoint-designer-2013-app-management-shared-service-proxy-is-not-installed/)

Still I'm facing this issue even if all the services are running!

Note: **I've created new Web Application and Site, here workflow is working fine.**
[image: Services on Server]

[image: Services on Web Application]

Comment: Go to Central Administration -> Application Management Tab-> Configure Service Application associations under Service Applications section -> Add App management service app proxy to default group if not already added.

Comment: Yes, This is default!

Comment: activate  Workflows can use app permissions  feature and test once

Comment: While activating the feature - Workflows can use app permissions
this again shows the error message as- App Management Shared Service Proxy is not installed.

Comment: Do you have site subscription service configured in the farm?

Comment: This is not a farm, I've installed Stand alone Server. So do I need to configure something?

Comment: Hi  Ram please post  your solution as answer  so that it will useful for other users

Comment: Still I'm struggling to rectify this issue, but I created New Web Application and Site, and everything working fine!

Answer (score 2):

**This issue might occur in case  of the following:**

- App Management Service is not installed. so try to [condifure it in the Application service](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/app-management-shared-service-proxy-is-not-installed/#configure-sharepoint-2016-app-management-service).
- App Management Service is stopped. so try to restart it.

[image]

---

**For more details, please check other causes for this issue at**

- [App Management Shared Service Proxy is not installed](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/app-management-shared-service-proxy-is-not-installed/)
- [HTTP service located at AppMng.svc is unavailable](https://debug.to/620/sharepoint-designer-2013-http-service-located-at-appmng-svc-is-unavailable)
- [App management shared service proxy is not installed SharePoint 2016](https://debug.to/781/app-management-shared-service-proxy-is-not-installed-sharepoint-2016)

Comment: App Management Service is started!
Is there anything else the above need to check?

Comment: check if the APP service is connected to your web application at connection service in application management

Comment: Please check the attached image in question!

Comment: go to CA > Application management > select your web application > and from the above ribbon select connected services > to check if App service is connected to the same web application or not

Comment: Checked! and added to the question and that App Management service is available.

Comment: delete the application service and create it again !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57323/discussion-between-ram-and-m-qassas).